# putting result of query into an object in python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Good Afternoon

I am trying to compile a well information and store the result of the fetch in list of objects as shown below using cx_Oracle 8.3.0 / python.

```
import cx_Oracle
def getOraCon(daDsn):
    global oraCon
    oraCon = cx_Oracle.connect(user='my_uid',password='my_pwd',dsn=daDsn)
    global oraCursor
    oraCursor = oraCon.cursor()
    executeDDLOracle("alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")

def getFetch(sql,cur):
    cur.execute(sql)
    return cur.fetchall()
    
def executeDDLOracle(strSQL):
    oraCursor.execute(strSQL)
    oraCon.commit()

def closeDbObject(dbObj):
    dbObj.close()
    dbObj = None
    del dbObj
    
def closeOra():
    oraCon.commit()
    closeDbObject(oraCursor)
    closeDbObject(oraCon)

def getFromList():
    getOraCon('CORPORATE_DB')
    executeDDLOracle('DROP TYPE T_TABLE')
    executeDDLOracle('create or replace TYPE T_RECORD IS OBJECT (w_id integer,w_lat varchar2(20), 
    sta_dpth integer,end_dpth integer)')
    executeDDLOracle('CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_TABLE AS TABLE OF T_RECORD')

    list_type = oraCon.gettype("T_RECORD")
    
    wb_list_main = list_type.newobject()
    wb_fetch=getFetch("select w_id, w_lat,sta_dpth, end_dpth from wb_data where lat_num >0", 
    oraCursor)
    for w_id, w_lat,sta_dpth, end_dpth in wb_fetch:
        wb_list = list_type.newobject()
        wb_list.type.attributes[0]=w_id
        wb_list.type.attributes[1]=w_lat
        wb_list.type.attributes[2]=sta_dpth
        wb_list.type.attributes[3]=end_dpth 
        wb_list_main.append(wb_list)
    closeOra()
```

I get  the error message:

```
<class 'cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError'>: Python value cannot be converted to a database value
```

at:

```
        wb_list_main.append(list_type)
```

I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Start by upgrading to [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) instead of the older cx_Oracle.  Then read the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#fetching-oracle-database-objects-and-collections) and [examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/tree/main/samples) about working with object types.  Then debug & simplify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Afternoon,

I thought I would share with you all what I have discovered. I hope this helps others in their work.

```
import cx_Oracle


def getOraCon(daDsn):
    global oraCon
    oraCon = cx_Oracle.connect(user='my_uid',password='my_pwd',dsn=daDsn)
    global oraCursor
    oraCursor = oraCon.cursor()
    executeDDLOracle("alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")

def makeDict(sql,cur):
    fetch = getFetch(sql,cur)
    return {key:val for key,val in fetch}   

def getFetch(sql,cur):
    cur.execute(sql)
    return cur.fetchall()
    
def executeDDLOracle(strSQL):
    oraCursor.execute(strSQL)
    oraCon.commit()
def closeDbObject(dbObj):
    dbObj.close()
    dbObj = None
def closeOra():
    oraCon.commit()
    closeDbObject(oraCursor)
    closeDbObject(oraCon)
    
def getData():
    getOraCon('CORPORATE_DB')
    executeDDLOracle('DROP TYPE T_TABLE')
    executeDDLOracle('create or replace TYPE T_RECORD IS OBJECT (w_id integer,w_lat 
    varchar2(20),sta_dpth integer,end_dpth integer)')
    executeDDLOracle('CREATE TYPE T_TABLE AS TABLE OF T_RECORD')
    list_type = oraCon.gettype("T_RECORD")
    wb_list = list_type.newobject()
    
    table_type = oraCon.gettype("T_TABLE")
    wb_table = table_type.newobject()

    wb_fetch=getFetch("select w_id, w_lat,sta_dpth, end_dpth from wb_data where lat_num >0", oraCursor) 
    
    for w_id, w_lat,sta_dpth, end_dpth in wb_fetch:
        wb_list.W_ID=w_id
        wb_list.W_LAT =w_lat
        wb_list.STA_DPTH =sta_dpth
        wb_list.END_DPTH =end_dpth 
        wb_table.append(wb_list)
    wb_fetch = None
    del wb_fetch
    test_fetch= oraCursor.execute("select * from table (:id_values)", 
    id_values=wb_table)
    
    for d in test_fetch.description:
        print(d)
    for r in test_fetch:
        print(r)
```

On a side note, while I agree that ideally I should update my driver to oracledb, currently I have no option to update the driver.